# Rackable Systems S5000PSL does not boot: 3 beeps, no post

Tags: boot, intel, battery

I have 6 Rackable Systems 1u servers, each with 2x4GB PC2 5300.

3 of them would boot and POST successfully, and the other 3 would not POST. Instead, these three would beep 3 times, indicating a memory fault as per the technical product specification. The diagnostic LEDs are red, amber amber.

However, if I swapped out the memory from one of the failing units into one of the working units, the ram was fine.

I've tried booting the failing units with only 1 stick of ram, and in different slots. Same result.

I had a suspicion that the CMOS batteries in my failing servers were dead. I removed the CMOS battery from one of the working servers, and placed it into one of the failing servers. The failing server still fails to POST. However, after re-inserting the battery back into the original server which was previously working, it also now fails to POST, with 3 beeps.

I concluded that the battery I chose may also have been dead, so I purchased some new 2032 batteries. I installed a new battery into the previously working server, and it still doesn't POST. I also tried reseting CMOS as per the user guide, still 3 beeps and no POST.

I'm out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Call the manufacturer/supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need clear CMOS settings by jumper. Maybe you will need to do it several time. Read about this procedure in the motherboard manual. It was happened when battery had low volts and CMOS settings was assigned some random values.
Sometimes is needed full power off the server (eject all power plugs) with ejecting battery. Use only new battery.

Use memtest86 to check all memory on good server.

The right way is using support email of the server manufacturer.

Comment: I have cleared the CMOS settings by jumper once as described in the motherboard manual. I will try it again.

Comment: Tried this process 3 times. Still does not boot.

Comment: Try again with ejecting all power plugs and battery before CMOS clear procedure.